# return statement no result in java

Tags: java, return

I have declared a method in a class named Teacher used return statement,

```
    public String info(){
    return  "Name is " +name +"Location is "+location;
```

Then I built the constructor then I called it from main class

```
Teacher t1= new Teacher("Tim","Guildford","Reader");
t1.info();
```

However both in cmd windows and intellij , there is no result.

But if I change the method type to void and use system.out.println, every thing is fine.

What is the problem here?

Comment: `t1.info()` just generates a `String`-object. You need to print it in order to see it on the screen.

Comment: `System.out.println(t1.info());`

Comment: you are not doing anything with the return value of that function...

Comment: I think it is unfair to downvote someone who is clearly a beginner...

Comment: @cricket_007 Downvotes are not personal. It is for distinguishing between good and bad content on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Gendarme - While I agree, I don't think there was anything wrong with the content under than the lack of understanding stated by "there is no result"

Answer (score 5):

You aren't using the return. You are calling `info()` but doing nothing with the return. Try this:

```
Teacher t1= new Teacher("Tim","Guildford","Reader");
System.out.println(t1.info());
```

Or store the `String` in a variable and use it later:

```
String test = t1.info();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing the result of your call.
Try `System.out.println(t1.info());`

Answer (score 0):

> and use system.out.println

Well, you aren't using that in the code you included in your question, that's why nothing ends up in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Since `info()` returns a String, `t1.info()` is a String. What you have done is to create a String called `t1.info()` with the value of `"Name is " +name +"Location is "+location`.

You have to do something with this String now.

If you want to print the String, just print it like this:

`System.out.print(t1.info());`